# Can't get getTotalLength() from <path>

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to create a SVG path element without appending it to the DOM and just compute its length, but for some reason i'm failing to do so.

After creating a fresh  element and adding a proper length, it doesn't let me call the getTotalLength() function to get its length. It's possible to recreate it by copypasting the following lines on any browser console:

```
var path = document.createElementNS('SVG', 'path');
d3.select(path).attr('d', 'M' + 10 + ',' + 10 + 'L' + 75 + ',' + 75);
path.getTotalLength();
```

This is the error that comes out of the last line of code:

> Uncaught TypeError: path.getTotalLength is not a function
>       at eval

I suspect and hope it's something really easy to spot and fix, but i'm short on ideas...

Comment: Well 'SVG' is not the correct namespace. Try `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well 'SVG' is not the correct namespace. You are trying to create a normal HTML-Element called `path`, which does not have any function called `path.getTotalLength()`.

Try `document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path')`

[SVG-Namespaces Crashcourse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)

```js
//var path = document.createElementNS('SVG', 'path');
var path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');
path.setAttribute('d','M' + 10 + ',' + 10 + 'L' + 75 + ',' + 75)
console.log(path.getTotalLength());
```

And here is the difference:

```js
//REM: No SVG element
var path1 = document.createElementNS('SVG', 'path');

//REM: SVG element
var path2 = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');

console.log('path1', path1 instanceof SVGElement);
console.log('path2', path2 instanceof SVGElement);
```